# Two equal signs in expression Swift

Tags: swift

I've added a `Date` extension that a variable for a Gregorian calendar like this:

```
extension Date {
    struct Gregorian {
        static let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    }
}
```

I want to add another `static var` inside the Gregorian struct for a calender where the `firstWeekday = 2`. Something like this:

```
struct Gregorian {
    static let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    static let calender2 = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).firstWeekday = 2
}
```

However, I can't have a statement with two `=`. How can I properly achieve adding this new struct member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define and call a closure to create `calendar2`:

```
struct Gregorian {
    static let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    static let calender2: Calendar = {
        var c = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        c.firstWeekday = 2
        return c
    }()
}
```